# Subtract a number column (representing years) from a Date column to create a new date colum

Tags: python, date, data-manipulation

I have column of dates ( Dtype = datetime64[ns]) and a column of integers (Dtype = Int16) in the same dataframe (df).
The integers column all have values between 20 and 100.

i want to create a new date column that is the Date column minus the integer columns
i.e.
df:

RepDate | Age | RevisedDate (To be calc)
1/1/19  | 20  | 1/1/99
4/2/22  | 50  | 4/2/72

so far i've tried:

```
df['RevisedDate'] = df['RepDate'] - pd.DateOffset(years= df['Age'])
```

but i get a TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

i've also tried deconstrucint and putting back torgether:

```
df['YofRevDate'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['RepDate']).year - df['Age']
df['MofRevDate'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['RepDate']).month
df['DofRevDate'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['RepDate']).day

df['RevisedDate'] = date(df['YofRevDate'], df['MofRevDate'], df['DofRevDate'])
```

but i get the same error on the last line.

your help will be much apricated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve that you have 2 ways:

- convert Age to something like timedelta in years (not supported in recent pandas versions), and add timedelta to date column
- parse date column, do age calculations, create new date column

I'm not sure how fast is my sollution (second option):

```
new_year = (df.RepDate.dt.year + df.Age).astype(str)
month_day = df.RepDate.dt.month.astype(str) + "-" + df.RepDate.dt.day.astype(str)
df['NewRepDate'] = pd.to_datetime(new_year + "-" + month_day,format="%Y-%m-%d")
df
```

Comment: Excellent thank you. it was the 2nd solution i used - looks like i was on the right path just the syntax is pd.to_datetime..